# Connect iOS app to Firebase Authentication Emulator

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have Firebase emulator suite enabled and linked to one of my test projects.
When I start the emulator, I see the following in the terminal.

[image: Terminal Output]

This is a **SwiftUI** app and it uses Authentication and Firestore currently.  When I configure Firestore, I do this when I initialize the application:

```
init() {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    let settings = Firestore.firestore().settings
    settings.host = "localhost:8080"
    settings.isPersistenceEnabled = false
    settings.isSSLEnabled = false
    Firestore.firestore().settings = settings
}
```

When I create a new user through the authentication process, it creates a user in the **live** version and I see that in my console there, but the corresponding document in the user collection is created in the emulator version of Cloud Firestore.  I cannot figure out how to set it up so that authentication, and eventually Storage and Functions will linked to the emulator when I have them running.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer.  I needed to add:

```
 Auth.auth().useEmulator(withHost:"localhost", port:9099)
```

to my initializer.  It is working now for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import SwiftUI
    import FirebaseCore
    import FirebaseAuth
    
    class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
              func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                               didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

        FirebaseApp.configure()
    
        //This line here 
    
        Auth.auth().useEmulator(withHost:"localhost", port:9099)
            
            
                return true
              }
            }
```